# CSS to make tab title containing fixed character length?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

i am using jquerytabs which add the tab dynamically on click of some button. Title can be of any character length . What i want is if
title contains more than 20 character, CSS should make it to 17 length character with 3 dots in front of it. here is title html
element which i see in firebug where Title is "Test Title length With Too many Characters"

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
<a href="#ui-tabs-4">Test Title length With Too many Characters/a>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>
</li>
```

**i am looking for css property so that i see the title as "Test Title length..." which is 17 character long and three dots in front of it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want something like this : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

i.e. add this class to the list item :

```
.truncate {
    width: 250px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works . Just a update looks like it needs to be added inside a element not in list elemnt. But that is enough for me.One more thing is is it possible when i hover over element <a> it displays the complete title?

Answer (score 0):

Since you added the javascript / jQuery tags to this question, here is the js / jQuery to truncate the text..

```
var text = $('a').text();
if(text.length > 17)​{
    $('a').text(text.substr(0,17) + "...")
}​
```

CSS is a cleaner way to achieve this, though.